# Run content of SetTimeout when clear timer

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have Timeout:

```
 clockifyButton.popupTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          popup.style.display = "none";
          aBrowser.runtime.sendMessage(
            {
              eventName: "startWithDescription",
              description,
              subject: title,
              tracker,
              taskid,
              tag,
              projectId: clockifyButton.selectedProject.id
            },
            response => {
              if (response.code === 400) {
                alert(
                  "Can't end entry without project/task/description or tags.Please edit your time entry."
                );
              } else {
                active = true;
                setButtonProperties(button, title, active);
                clockifyButton.inProgressDescription = title;
                aBrowser.storage.sync.set({
                  timeEntryInProgress: response.data
                });
              }
            }
          );
        }, 5000);
```

And I'm searching solution how I can sendMessage, when I clearTimeout(popupTimer) from another sourse. Thanks in forward!!!

Comment: There is no built in way to intercept the `clearTimeout` call. You have t do it yourself - wrap your timer ID in a small module and isolate it from external calls, then provide your own `clear` method that will remove the timeout and also do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling the timeout will prevent the callback from being fired, so you will need to call it yourself at the point the timer is cancelled.

Try something like this:

```
class CancelableWait {
    constructor(func, delay) {
        this.func = func;
        this._timer = setTimeout(() => this.cancel(), delay);
    }

    cancel() {
        if (this._timer) {
            clearTimeout(this._timer);
            this._timer = null;
            this.func();
        }
    }
}

console.log("Starting 5 second timer..");
let waiter = new CancelableWait(() => console.log("Fired!"), 5000);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Cancelling..");
    waiter.cancel();
}, 2000);
```

This will only fire the callback once regardless of whether that's due to the natural conclusion of the timer, or from an explicit call to `cancel`.

Comment: Good idea, thanks, but I rethink my idea, and decided that it is better to make a 
separate function, to use anywhere in my code))